Map complex DTOs to Entity via Mapstruct
How can you effectively map a complex DTO that includes nested collections of objects to an entity in Spring Boot using the MapStruct library? I can map simple object, but what if I need to map this nested elements from collection?
I am using Kotlin and Springboot.
Some best practices?

you can use decorator on your mapper where you can call generated map function by MapStruct and extend result in your decorator.
Example:

Firstly create an abstract class:
@DecoratedWith(NameOfYourDecorator::class)  abstract class NameOfYourMapperDecorated : YourMapper

Create decorator and map list from DTO to list of your entity:


 open class BatchMapperDecorator : BatchMapperDecorated() { 
    // inject your mapper
    private var mapperProperty: YourMapper = 
    Mappers.getMapper(YourMapper::class.java)
        
    override fun mapMethod(source: DTO): YourEntity 
    {
        val result = mapperProperty.mapMethod(source)
        result.collection = source.collection.map { 
            … map logic … 
        }.toList()

        return result
}




It could works, thank you!
